# electron menu 'roles' don't seem to be working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

This is the standard code given as an example on the electron website for creating a custom menu:

```
    const template = [
  {
    label: 'Edit',
    submenu: [
      {role: 'undo'},
      {role: 'redo'},
      {type: 'separator'},
      {role: 'cut'},
      {role: 'copy'},
      {role: 'paste'},
      {role: 'pasteandmatchstyle'},
      {role: 'delete'},
      {role: 'selectall'}
    ]
  },
  {
    label: 'View',
    submenu: [
      {role: 'reload'},
      {role: 'forcereload'},
      {role: 'toggledevtools'},
      {type: 'separator'},
      {role: 'resetzoom'},
      {role: 'zoomin'},
      {role: 'zoomout'},
      {type: 'separator'},
      {role: 'togglefullscreen'}
    ]
  },
  {
    role: 'window',
    submenu: [
      {role: 'minimize'},
      {role: 'close'}
    ]
  },
  {
    role: 'help',
    submenu: [
      {
        label: 'Learn More'
      }
    ]
  }
]

if (process.platform === 'darwin') {
  template.unshift({
    label: app.getName(),
    submenu: [
      {role: 'about'},
      {type: 'separator'},
      {role: 'services', submenu: []},
      {type: 'separator'},
      {role: 'hide'},
      {role: 'hideothers'},
      {role: 'unhide'},
      {type: 'separator'},
      {role: 'quit' }
    ]
  })

  // Edit menu
  template[1].submenu.push(
    {type: 'separator'},
    {
      label: 'Speech',
      submenu: [
        {role: 'startspeaking'},
        {role: 'stopspeaking'}
      ]
    }
  )

  // Window menu
  template[3].submenu = [
    {role: 'close'},
    {role: 'minimize'},
    {role: 'zoom'},
    {type: 'separator'},
    {role: 'front'}
  ]
}

    const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template)
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
```

However, this does not work properly.
It does set my menu, however, all the fields are just blank, without any text.

If I add labels, like so, this fixes the problem:

```
      {
        label: 'About',
        role: 'about'
      },
```

In the case of `about` the `role` attribute also works, i.e., when I click on the about menu item, a window pops up. However, the same is not the case with `quit`

```
  {
    label: 'Quit',
    role: 'quit',
  }
```

Although the `role` is `quit` here, it does not quit my application, neither is it clickable at all. I could, of course, add all of this functionality myself, add labels to every sub item, functions, accelerators for short cuts, etc., but then I do not see the point of using `role` at all?

Am I missing something, or is there a setting I need to consider before applying those attributes?

Comment: Ok, I was indeed using an older version of electron, thank you for that. I think I used an old version of the prebuilt. Everything works now, apart from `forcereload`. I don't understand though why `togglefullscreen` should by default close the dev tools?

Comment: I made a mistake (it was late). I meant `toggledevtools` will only open the dev tools but not close them. Deleting earlier comment.